# what is event log permission in security permissions of event logs

Tags: windows

I have a group called event log in security permissions list of event log which I did not configure I want to know whether it is a default user group or not

http://tinypic.com/r/2dv6545/8

check with the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this on Windows 7 or Server 2008 (or newer)? If so, then [this article](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/7718185f-8932-4019-a1b1-d1446ff4cb94/what-is-eventlog-security-group?forum=winserversecurity) will answer your question. In short:

> Eventlog and EventSystem are Virtual Accounts. Virtual Accounts were introduced in Windows Server 2008 and Windows 7.
>
> (1)Virtual Accounts aren't created but are used to run services. You access them by typing NT SERVICE[service name] into the 'This account' field on the service's Log On tab in the service management console and leaving the password fields blank. Virtual Accounts have the same permissions as Network Service: They have standard user rights on the local machine but communicate with the network as the local computer account.

Comment: Thank you kate and I have another doubt..(i.e) can you give me detailed explanation or link about windows user account like                 1.what is shared user account 2.what is network service account etc..